# cgo Calling functions defined in a C++ (that are in namespaces)

Tags: c++, go, cgo

I have a library that I want to use which only provides C++ header files and a static library. Go is unable to parse the namespaces that it is wrapped in.

I have looked at this: [How to use C++ in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713214/how-to-use-c-in-go) and it makes sense, but there are no namespaces involved there.

This is the C++ code in question that when imported causes issues (only the beginning shown):

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>

namespace ctre {
namespace phoenix {
```

And here is the result of compiling:

```
./include/ctre/phoenix/ErrorCode.h:4:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace ctre {
 ^~~~~~~~~
./include/ctre/phoenix/ErrorCode.h:4:16: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token
 namespace ctre {
```

Is there any way that I can provide a C wrapper which avoids this problem?

Comment: Since C++ compilers normally mangle names and add secret arguments and so on, and cgo is designed to call unmangled C functions without secret extra arguments and so on, you must provide the C wrapper or write your C++ functions as C functions. C wrappers don't have standard ways to access C++ namespaces. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/18945419/1256452 for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a C wrapper header file. Then I created a CPP file which bridges said C interface with the library CPP headers and library.

The C header understands my library object as a void pointer, and my CPP implementation has to cast it in order to access all of its functions.

The `extern "C"` part is very important and prevent Go from freaking out - It prevents the CPP compiler from mangling function names.

Of course, also link the binary with the proper LDFLAGS.

phoenix.h

```cpp
typedef void CTalon;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

CTalon* CTRE_CreateTalon(int port);

void CTRE_Set(CTalon* talon, double output);

void CTRE_Follow(CTalon* slave, CTalon* master);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

phoenix.cpp

```cpp
#include "phoenix.h" // My C wrapper header

#include "ctre/phoenix/motorcontrol/can/TalonSRX.h" // Actual CPP header from library

#define TALON(ctalon) ((ctre::TalonSRX*) ctalon) // Helper macro to make converting to library object easier. Optional

namespace ctre { // Specific to my library which has a lot of long namespaces. Unrelated to problem
    using ctre::phoenix::motorcontrol::ControlMode;
    using ctre::phoenix::motorcontrol::can::TalonSRX;
}

extern "C" {
    CTalon* CTRE_CreateTalon(int port) {
        return (CTalon*) new ctre::TalonSRX(port);
    }

    void CTRE_Set(CTalon* talon, double output) {
        TALON(talon)->Set(ctre::ControlMode::PercentOutput, output);
    }

    void CTRE_Follow(CTalon* slave, CTalon* master) {
        TALON(slave)->Follow(*(TALON(master)));
    }
}
```